# The problem to grant permissions in WebView+webRTC in Android app

Tags: android, webview, chromium

The problem is appeared in my WebView after updated Chrome up to 79 ver. 2019.12.18 in Android device. My WebView stopped requesting for permission to provide access to the camera and microphone, though with early Chrome's versions(56, 78) it's worked. I've use that webRTC-provider: https://trueconf.ru/. I got that's error in my logs every 15 seconds:

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
```

If I try to open webRTC-session in Chrome, it's work. So, I think, there is some divergence between Chrome and Chromium, or something like that.
I've created little app, that emulation my origin code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int RC_CAMERA_AND_VOICE = 1;
    private static final int RC_CAMERA_AND_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int RC_CAMERA_AND_CAPTURE = 3;


    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkPermissions();
    }

    private void checkPermissions() {

        Log.e("VideoChat", "checkPermissions");


        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this.getApplication(), 
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplication(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},0);
        } else {
            this.startWebView();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        this.startWebView();
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private void startWebView() {
        webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                Log.e("VideoChat", "onPermissionRequest");
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }

        });

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://your.webrtc.provider");
    }
}
```

My Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_LOCAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="true" />
```

Need to know: I did not notice this problem with other webRTC-providers, but I must to use my provider. Any help, please.

Comment: Have you found a solution?